# mysql error for update - "' You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I try to change such as steve to david all membe that is steve must change to david I have a bout 10000 record and if select distinct surba I have 1251 so I try to use this sql statement to change them all at once:

```
UPDATE memba2
SET t1.surba = t2.surba
FROM memba2 t1
INNER JOIN memba t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

This is an error I get. Please help.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'FROM memba2 t1 INNER JOIN memba t2 ON t1.id=t2.id' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `INNER JOIN` in your UPDATE statement is slightly incorrect,
you can try :-

```
UPDATE memba2, memba
SET memba.surba=memba2.surba
WHERE memba.id=memba2.id;
```

If you want to `use INNER JOIN`,
the correct syntax is :-

```
UPDATE memba2 INNER JOIN memba
SET memba.surba=memba2.surba
WHERE memba.id=memba2.id;
```

OR

```
UPDATE memba2 INNER JOIN memba ON (memba.id=memba.id)
SET memba.surba=memba2.surba
WHERE memba.id=memba2.id;
```

Comment: I try 3 scripts  it like some time steve change to david some time steve change to Linda ...

Comment: I have to table memba  and memba2   memba2.surba is unique  memba2.surba is duplicate  it have steve in many rows in  memba

Comment: You really have to consider to clean-up your data.And you should make your id unique (primary key) after you done de-duplication.

Comment: I want to change steve to x but all steve must change to x so i want to select from memba2.surba

Comment: I have two tables memba and memba2 memba.surba is duplicate memba2.surba is unique it have steve in many rows in memba (My prevoius coment is not correct)

Answer (score 0):

```
update memba a join (select  min(id) as id,surba from memba group by surba) b on b.surba = a.surba join memba2 c on c.id = b.id
set a.surba = c.surba
```